# how to Show or Read docx file

Tags: java, android, ms-word, docx

I am new to rendering files in android, and I want to render or display a docx file in my application.

I had already extract text from docx file, but now I want to extract images from the docx file as well.

I've found several ways to display images in pure Java, but are there any good examples for Android?

I tried this code to fetch Images but not working...

```
public void extractImages(Document xmlDoc)
{
    NodeList binDataList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("w:drawings");
    String fileName = "";
    Node currentNode;
    for(int i = 0; i < binDataList.getLength(); i++)
    {
        currentNode = binDataList.item(i);
        if(currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && ((Element)currentNode).hasAttribute("w:name"))
        {               
            File newImageFile = new File(picDirectory, ((Element)currentNode).getAttribute("w:name").replaceFirst("wordml://", ""));
            if(newImageFile.exists())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if(writeImage(newImageFile, currentNode))
                {
                    //Print some success message
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for comparison of files? I have same issue! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411678/docx4j-giving-wrong-result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [AndroidDocxToHtml](https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml), which I made to demonstrate using docx4j on Android.

A couple of caveats.

First, that project does not include all docx4j dependencies, only the ones required for docx to HTML conversion.  So if you want to do other things, you may need others of the dependencies.

Second, docx4j requires JAXB - see [this blog post re JAXB on Android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/) - and JAXB context init on app startup takes a while depending on the device. There are ways to work around this, but at extra effort.

If all you want to do is extract the images, and you don't care how they relate to the text, you could just look for image parts.  You might use [OpenXML4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxml4j/) for that, and avoid JAXB.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to create an image in Android is to use the [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) factory methods.

The `BitmapFactory` class has methods for creating a `Bitmap` from a byte array, a file or an InputStream.

Once you have a `Bitmap` object you can display it by setting it on an `ImageView` in your layout using the [`setImageBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) method.

Comment: the thing is how can i get the images from the docx file i know that how to show & convert i want how to get or extract images from the docx file.......

Comment: You would need to find a library that can read .docx files. I've never had to do this before, but any decent library should provide a method for extracting image data from the file. I'd suggest trying Google: http://goo.gl/Bcw8e

Answer (score 5):

You can just unzip the file (rename to .zip and open it) then you can investigate the folder structure, where the images are located etc.

Comment: i had unzipped it & get all the images but i want them in respective manner like.. 
1. TEXT 
2. Image then again text in that manner.....