# Using raw folder in android

Tags: android

I am trying to access a file placed in raw folder. I am able to read the contents of a text file but I need to access a word(.docx) file with all the text formatting applied to it.
How can I achieve it? Please someone help me!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974468/how-to-read-doc-docx-xls-files-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to display the docs file in Android using 3rd party libraries.

However, JasonPluText has created a demo showing [AndroidDocxToHTML](https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml)

See this question for more details: [how to Show or Read docx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447865/how-to-show-or-read-docx-file)