# How to display MS word file in the textview in android

Tags: java, android

I have a .docx file saved in assets folder. I have a textview with a button.
When i click the button i want to display the .docx file in the textview of the same activity.I know to display .txt file,but how to display .docx file.
I do not want to make use of Intent.ACTION_VIEW or olivedoclibrary.
.docx may contain anything like images ,text everything.It should display the docx file as it is.

Coded that i founded was not properly understood.Please help
What would be the solution to this problem atleast the explanation to the problem.

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Show or Read docx file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447865/how-to-show-or-read-docx-file)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697784/displaying-a-ms-word-file-in-viewsay-textview-in-android
Thanks

Comment: I saw that,but i do not want to use olivedoclibrary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Microsoft Office Library (.doc, .docx, .xls, .ppt, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854947/android-microsoft-office-library-doc-docx-xls-ppt-etc)

Answer (score 2):

> When i click the button i want to display the .docx file in the textview of the same activity.

First, Android does not have a DOCX parser. You will need to find a third-party library that offers this (or write your own), then use something like a `SpannableStringBuilder` to build up the content to show in the `TextView`.

Second, `TextView` has support for limited formatting. Lots of things may be in a DOCX file that cannot be shown in a `TextView`.

You may have somewhat better luck finding a DOCX->HTML converter and showing the results in a `WebView` though even that may not rise to the level of "It should display the docx file as it is".

Comment: If not .docx, any other way of displaying .docx file content by converting the .docx file